# Принцип работы flex-basis, расчет размеров внутреннего элемента

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Здравствуйте, ув. вебмастера! Уже второй день ломаю голову и посторонние предметы, думая над вопросом: https://jsfiddle.net/sm8s9x0k/

Два элемента находятся во flex-контейнере c `direction:column` обоим задан `flex-basis: 49%` (стр.57 в примере). Внутри каждого из элементов лежит картинка, которая по задумке должна подстраиваться под размеры flex-элемента, который исходя из базиса занимает 49% родительского контейнера. Но такого не происходит, пока я не задам flex-элементу размер `height: 49%;` помимо свойства flex-basis.При этом картинке-дочке flex-элемента задано `height:100%;`

Объясните пожалуйста почему размер картинки-дочки не расчитывается от flex-basis? 
Верно ли в данном случае то решение, до которого дошел я?
Ну и если не трудно объясните логику расчета размеров в данном случае, спасибо!

Comment: Не понятно описали проблему. Картинка распирает ячейку колонки из-за чего та становится больше положенного размера?

Comment: Вы можете отключить строку №58 посмотреть на проблему. Реально ли поджать изображение под размеры flex-basis: 49%, не указывая помимо базиса height: 49%?

Comment: Попробую наперед ответить: добавьте к img{max-width: 100%} и к .items__column-item{min-height: 0;}

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sm8s9x0k/1/

Comment: Я Вас очень благодарю, но не могли бы вы объяснить мне логику работы всего этого?

Comment: написал ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в дочерний флекс элемент положить длинную неразрывную строку, например *"aaaaaaaaaaaa"* (или в вашем случае большую картинку), то этот элемент растянется и за собой растянет флекс блок (из-за чего сломает задуманный вами лейаут)

Чтобы это исправить и на первое место в приоритет поставить размеры лейаута, а не его контент нужно для дочерних флексов указывать `min-width: 0` (строчный флекс) `min-height: 0` (колончатый флекс). Это решение с первого взгляда кажется хаком, но это поведение описано в спецификации и все нормально.

Подробнее здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022288/how-to-keep-a-flex-item-from-overflowing-due-to-its-text